# Recyclerview not display vediothumbnail

Tags: android, video, android-recyclerview

i am working and i want to display a video in recyclerview from server  its geting data not displaying video thumbnail its showing only text and displaing error thumbnail i dont know where i am wrong please review my code and tell me where i am wrong ,

**myActivity**

```
public class TestingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private List<TestingModel> listiIems;
 //Creating Views
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
 private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
 private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testingactivity);
    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_test);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    listiIems = new ArrayList<>();
    //Calling method to get data
    getData();
}
//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData() {
    String Data_Url="http://www.example.com/vedio.json";
    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
    //Creating a json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Data_Url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        TestingModel item = new TestingModel();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            item.setUrl_image(json.getString("audio"));
            item.setTest_name(json.getString("txt"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listiIems.add(item);
    }

    //Finally initializing our adapter
    adapter = new TestingAdapter(listiIems, this);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class TestingModel {
public String getUrl_image() {
    return url_image;
}

public void setUrl_image(String url_image) {
    this.url_image = url_image;
}

public String getTest_name() {
    return test_name;
}

public void setTest_name(String test_name) {
    this.test_name = test_name;
}

 private String url_image;
 private String test_name;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class TestingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;
String url;
//List of superHeroes
List<TestingModel> listItems;
public TestingAdapter(List<TestingModel> listItems, Context context) {
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.testing_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    TestingModel items = listItems.get(position);
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest1.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(items.getUrl_image(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.placeholder, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(items.getUrl_image(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(items.getTest_name());
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            url = listItems.get(position).getUrl_image();
            Log.e("urlis","==>"+url);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.testingimage);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texting_text);
    }
  }
}
```

help me

Comment: the code looks fine. check the urls to see if they are valid. Also, if you may, consider Picasso. its much simpler

Comment: urls is correct value is properly received but not displaying thumbnail

Comment: try using glide or Picasso for image loading from url.

Comment: @GyanendraMani please tell me how to use i never used glide and picasso

Comment: can you post your image url here?

Comment: if possible you can extract the thumbnail image by using  using backend code and the can send in the response of api call.
for eg:
"video":"http:\/\/www.jaisainath.com\/virtuem\/evideo\/json\/video\/3.3gp","txt":"Antarctic penguins ielts reading passage","thumb_url":"http:\\a.png"}

Comment: or you can check this library if you want to extract the thumbnail in android code:
https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Check in adapter. Are you getting url is image or video. If url is contain image then need to check in ImageLoader Library. you can better use with glide and picasso.

Its very easy to use picasso. You can found picasso from this link
http://square.github.io/picasso/

> **Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(imageView);**

If your url contain video then you have to create thumbnail from url using Thumnail Util

> Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,
>   Thumbnails.MINI_KIND); imageview.setBitmapImage(thumb);